# Show that $\frac{N}{m}((N+m)\ln(N+m)+(N-m)\ln(N-m)-2N\ln(N)) \to 1$ when $N\gg m$

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, brownian-motion

$$\frac{N}{m^2}((N+m)\ln(N+m)+(N-m)\ln(N-m)-2N\ln(N))\to 1 \text{ when  } N \gg m$$

I got this expression from fiddling around with Brownian motion. From inputing values for $N$ and $m$ I can see that it goes towards 1 very quickly, even with small differences, like $N=10$ and $m=1$. Is L'Hôpital the way to go here or what?

Edit: $\frac{N}{m}$ was wrong, the $m$ should be squared like it is now.

Comment: When you say $\to 1$, do you mean $\to 1$ as $N\to\text{something}$ or as $m\to\text{something}$ or what? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I changed "$N>>m$ to $N\gg m$.  MathJax codes mathematical notation in a way that is based on the way LaTeX does it, so it's fairly sophisticated if you know how to use it.  If you google "latex binary operation symbols", you'll find stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks for the MathJax edit, didn't find the correct symbol when I was writing that. As for the first comment, I guess I mean as $N \to \inf$ for the expression to go to exactly 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite this as

$$ \frac{1}{m^2} \ln{\left( \frac{(N+m)^{N+m}(N-m)^{N-m}}{N^{2N}}   \right)^N}$$

Then you want to show that the quantity inside the logarithm converges to $e$. Write it as
$$\left( \frac{(N+m)^m}{(N-m)^m}\right)^N \cdot \left( \frac{N^2-m^2}{N^2}\right)^{N^2}$$.

The first part goes to $e^{2m^2}$, the second is  $e^{-m^2}$. You can see the second part since it is $$\left(1-\frac{m^2}{N^2}\right)^{N^2}.$$ It is a known calculus fact that $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n \rightarrow e^x$ so you use this. 
As for the first part, write it as $$e^{mN\ln{\frac{N+m}{N-m}}}$$ and use L'Hospital.